# What purpose, if any, do skill points serve once you have unlocked all perks?

Tags: forza-horizon-2

At this stage in Forza Horizon 2 I have accumulated all perks that were available to earn via skill points.  At this point, do skill points serve any residual purpose in the game?

Put another way, while unlocking the perks I adapted my driving style to attempt to earn maximum skill points while still winning races.  This was not necessarily the fastest way around a course, however.  At this point I am wondering if there is any need to continue to focus on obtaining skill points or if I should just focus on winning races now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though there are no more perks to unlock, driving skillfully still awards EXP bonuses. So none of the points are really "wasted" as you will continue to level up and earn bonuses that way.

Comment: I was really hoping there would be a way to spend those points or something, but in the absence of other answers, I think yours is probably the most accurate.